# randomly select 4 rows in each list of lists in a for loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I would need to select randomly from each a list of lists 4 rows and then create a dataframe with all the lists with randomly selected lines.

I am giving a list of lists as a reproducble example:

```
list1 <- list(a=1:10, b=20:30) 
list2 <- list(d=1:10, e=20:30) 

list_all <- list(list1, list2)
```

I need to get in return a,b,c,d but with only randomly selected 4 rows.

How could I do it?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```r
lapply(unlist(list_all, recursive = FALSE), sample, 4)
#> $a
#> [1] 3 1 7 8
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 27 22 26 20
#> 
#> $d
#> [1]  7 10  1  9
#> 
#> $e
#> [1] 27 22 23 30
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yes, you're right. That's better.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `rapply` and `sample` could help

```
> rapply(list_all, sample, size = 4, how = "replace")
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1]  7  9 10  5

[[1]]$b
[1] 24 28 29 25


[[2]]
[[2]]$d
[1]  5 10  2  8

[[2]]$e
[1] 28 20 23 22
```

Comment: it works both in this example and in my data list thanks! then only thing is that with my list I get the selected row and the rest NA, how could I avoid this? THanks again!

Comment: @i.b I have no idea why you got `NA`. Did you try solutions from other answers?

Comment: yes but with my own list, your solution is the only one that worked, only that instead of only having 4 rows per list, I get 10, first 4 with values and the rest NA

Comment: @i.b I have no clue without your own list, probably you can try `rapply(list_all, \(x) x[sample.int(length(x), max(length(x),4))], how = "replace")`

Answer (score 1):

use `rapply`:

```
rapply(list_all, sample,size = 4, how = 'list')
# rapply(list_all, \(x)sample(x,4), how = 'list')
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 3 1 2 4

[[1]]$b
[1] 21 22 24 23


[[2]]
[[2]]$d
[1] 2 3 4 7

[[2]]$e
[1] 24 25 21 22
```